# How to deal with short reads with Winsock2?

Tags: c++, winsock2

I'm having trouble with receiving data over a network using Winsock2, with Windows. I'm trying to use a simple client and server system to implement a file transfer program. With our current code, the last packet coming in doesn't get appended to the file because it's not the size of the buffer. So, the file transfer doesn't quite completely, throws an error, and breaks. It's not always the very last packet, sometimes it's earlier.

Here is a snippet of the **Server code**:

```
int iResult;
ifstream sendFile(path,  ifstream::binary);
char* buf;

if (sendFile.is_open()) {
printf("File Opened!\n");
// Sends the file
while (sendFile.good()) {
    buf = new char[1024];
    sendFile.read(buf, 1024);
    iResult = send(AcceptSocket, buf, (int)strlen(buf)-4, 0 );
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(AcceptSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    //printf("Bytes Sent: %d\n", iResult);
}
sendFile.close();
```

}

And here is a snippet of the **Client code**:

```
int iResult;
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN] = "";

do {
    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if ( iResult > 0){
        printf("%s",recvbuf);
        myfile.write(recvbuf, iResult);
    }
    else if ( iResult == 0 ) {
        wprintf(L"Connection closed\n");
    } else {
        wprintf(L"recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }

} while( iResult > 0 );

myfile.close();
```

When trying to transfer a file that is a dictionary, it can break at random times. For example, one run broke early in the S's and appended weird characters to the end, which isn't rare:

```
...
sayable
sayer
sayers
sayest
sayid
sayids
saying
sayings
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠recv failed with error: 10054
```

What can I do to handle these errors and weird characters?

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening on the server side. You're getting a "Connection reset by peer" error.

This line - `buf = new char[1024];` - is clearly problematic and is likely causing the server to crash because it runs out of memory. There is no clean up happening. Start by adding the appropriate `delete` statement, probably best placed after the `send` call. If that doesn't fix it I would use a small test file and step through that while loop in the server code.

P.S. A better solution than using `new` and `delete` in your loop is to reuse the existing buff. The compiler might optimize this mistake out but if it doesn't you're severely hindering the applications performance. I think you actually should just move `buf = new char[1024];` outside of the loop. `buf` is a char pointer so `read` will continue to overwrite the contents of `buf` if you pass it `buf`. Re allocating the buffer over and over is not good.

With regard to the error MSDN says:

An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. This normally results if the peer application on the remote host is suddenly stopped, the host is rebooted, the host or remote network interface is disabled, or the remote host uses a hard close (see setsockopt for more information on the SO_LINGER option on the remote socket). This error may also result if a connection was broken due to keep-alive activity detecting a failure while one or more operations are in progress. Operations that were in progress fail with WSAENETRESET. Subsequent operations fail with WSAECONNRESET.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I have tried moving `buf = new char[1024];` outside of the loop, and more words in the file broke (random weird characters added on to the end of them). In regards to the server running out of memory - the file we're trying to send is less than 1mb, and the PC's have multiple gb of ram. Could that really be the issue?

Comment: @iaacp that could not be the issue then. How about appending a null terminator to the string? If you're char array doesn't have a newline or null terminator you're going to get a garbage. I don't know if read does this automatically but I don't see any code there to handle this.

Answer (score -1):

First, using the **new** operator in a loop might not be good, especially without a corresponding **delete**.  I'm not a C++ expert, though (only C) but I think it is worth checking.

Second, socket error 10054 is "connection reset by peer" which tells me that the server is not performing what is called a *graceful close* on the socket.  With a graceful close, WinSock will wait until all pending data has been received by the other side before sending the FIN message that breaks the connection.  It is likely that your server is is just closing immediately after the final buffer is given to WinSock without any time for it to get transmitted.  You'll want to look into the `SO_LINGER` socket options -- they explain the graceful vs non-graceful closes.

Simply put, you either need to add your own protocol to the connection so that the client can acknowledge receipt of the final data block, or the server side needs to call `setsocketopt()` to set a `SO_LINGER` timeout so that WinSock will wait for the TCP/IP acknowledgement from the client side for the final block of data before issuing the socket close across the network.  If you don't do at least **ONE** of those things, then this problem will occur.

There's also another article about that here that you might want to look at:

[socket error 10054](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558738/socket-error-10054)

Good luck!

Comment: If you new an array, need to use delete[] to get rid of it.

Comment: Setting a positive SO_LINGER timeout only causes `close()` to block while there is data pending to be sent. There is no guarantee that it waits for that data to be ACKd before issuing the FIN, and no necessity for it to do so.